# Running MobileNetV2 in Cloud Functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to get features for a given image using Cloud Functions v2, Python 3.11, and Tensorflow 2.15.

For some reason, the model is not returning when fetching predictions so my function timeouts.

I've been adding more CPU, 8 to be exact and 32GB of Memory but I still can't find a way to return any results.

This is part of the code I'm executing:

```
from keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input

# include_top=False - Excludes the final classification layers, focusing on extracting features.
# pooling='avg' - Adds a global average pooling layer to condense feature maps to a single vector (embedding).
# weights='imagenet' - Uses weights pre-trained on ImageNet for better feature extraction.
model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')

def extract_embeddings(image_url):
  
    response = requests.get(image_url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    img = image.load_img(BytesIO(response.content), target_size=(224, 224))

    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    img_array = preprocess_input(img_array)

    embeddings = model.predict(img_array)
    print("embeddings predicted")
    return embeddings.flatten()
```

I'm a bit lost here, so hoping someone can help

I tried scaling my resources without any luck

Comment: This is not very much in my domain... but don't you have to configure something to tell Keras to multiprocess your prediction? If so, you may have 1000 cores but the framework does not know, it will still use a single thread... Have you checked it?
Checkout this link
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93785/how-do-i-get-keras-to-use-more-than-1-core